# Keyboard shortcuts for copy paste in 14.04 not working

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, copy, paste

Keyboard shortcuts for copy paste in 14.04 has stopped working for me in last couple of weeks. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not give any result to me. I had to right click to use copy and paste. Any idea in 14.04 to fix it ? Many thanks.

Comment: If you are talking about the shortcuts in the command line terminal, then it's ctrl+shift+c and ctrl+shift+v... if your shortcuts don't work elsewhere, it's possible that you reassigned them somewhere by mistake

Comment: Thanks @Neni , I am talking in general. Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V does not work anywhere on PC. How can I make it available ?

Comment: Have you assigned somewhere some custom shortcuts? Like in System Settings (keyboard section), Unity Tweak Tool or ccsm? Check there if these shortcuts are assigned for something else! I have no other idea why your problem could occur...

Comment: @Neni , I do not recall ever doing so. It was working fine since a couple of weeks. The last time I installed something on this computer was at least 2 months back.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong... you may search for similar issues or wait for better suggestions... sorry